# LIst of Functions called during script execution

Tags: uft14

I'm trying to consolidate functions for a very large automation suite using UFT.  There are many functions that get called.  I'm curious if anyone has a code snippet that uses the UFT object model, or something similar, that would trace functions called into either the output tab, a text file, or something else that could be perused to see which said functions were called during a script run.

A call to write an info row in the test results reviewer, output tab, etc. can be added, but it's obviously a very laborious exercise.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub GetAction(piRow,ByRef pstrActionName)
'On Error Resume Next
'Declaration
Dim objxl,objwb,rowno,strAction,objws
Set objxl=CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'Open the Datasheet
Set objwb=objxl.workbooks.open(excelpath)
objxl.visible=False
objxl.displayalerts=False
Set objws=objxl.activeworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1")
'Get the ActionName
strAction=objxl.cells(piRow,1)
    pstrActionName=strAction
End If
If Err.Number<>0 Then
    Msgbox "GetAction:"&"Error :"&Cstr(Err.Description)
End If
Set objws=Nothing
Set objwb=Nothing
'Close and Quit from Excel
objxl.Quit
    End Sub'GetAction
```

Write all the function names in a excel sheet

Call above function which will read function names from the excel sheet

call function using below step

```
call pstrActionName
```